# Get linked-list data to String array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, linked-list

I have this function where `list` is a pointer to a linked list. This is the list struct which contains nodes with data.

```
typedef struct node{
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
}NODE;
```

```
typedef struct list{
    NODE* head;
    char *id;
    struct list *next;
    int size;
}LIST;
```

My goal is to take every data from the list and return it as a `**char`. It looks like it works but the line where i do  `words = (char**) calloc(numOfWords*wordLength,sizeof(char));` I'm not sure if it's correct and how it works exactly. Can you see anything that is going wrong in my code and help me? Thanks.

```
char **reset_words(LIST *list){
    char ** words;
    int i = 0,j = 0,wordLength,numOfWords = list->size;
    NODE *p;
    for (p = list->head; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        wordLength = my_strlen(p->data);
        words = (char**) calloc(numOfWords*wordLength,sizeof(char));
        for(int k=0;k < wordLength;k++){
            words[i][j] = p->data[k];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return words;
}
```

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc` (or `calloc`, or `realloc`), it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After i looked at your code here are some changes:

1. If your list is a correctly done linked-list and all nodes have the same size of data then you could simply do  `wordLength = strlen(list->head->data)`.
2. Initialize words outside the loops. The way i did it should work.
3. Since you have string you can simply do  `strcpy(words[i],p->data)` to add the string to your words array.

Try this out let me know if it works.

```
char **reset_words(LIST *list){
    char ** words;
    int i = 0,j = 0,wordLength = strlen(list->head->data),numOfWords = list->size;
    NODE *p;
    words = (char **)malloc(numOfWords * sizeof(char *));
    for (int h=0; h<numOfWords; h++)
        words[h] = (char *)calloc(wordLength,sizeof(char));
    for (p = list->head; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        strcpy(words[i],p->data);
        i++;
    }
    return words;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        wordLength = my_strlen(p->data);
```

I do not know, what `my_strlen()` does.  But you have to keep in mind to reserve additional space for the trailing `\0`.

```
        words = (char**) calloc(numOfWords*wordLength,sizeof(char));
```

This does not make much sense... `numOfWords` seem to be the number of nodes while `wordLength` is the length of the actual data.  So `numOfWords * wordLength` is something which might be used to calculate to total amount of space for all characters (but only, when `wordLength` is the length of the largest string).

Depending on you requirements (do you really need to copy the strings or does a reference suffice?), you can express this as:

```
char **words = calloc(list->size, sizeof words[0]);
size_t i = 0;
for (struct node *p = list->head; p; p = p->next) {
    if (1)
         words[i++] = p->data;
    else
         words[i++] = strdup(p->data);
}
```

Comment: My strlen() is correct, it does exactly the same thing as the normal strlen(). I assume that all words have the same length. So length of the first is the length for all words. The method should return char[][] or *char[] or **char which is basically trhe same thing.
A would like to copy the words, a reference would not help me.